# Is there a way to show/Invoke the Salesforce standard edit record from the VF page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, edit

Is there a way to show/Invoke the salesforce standard edit record from the VF page?

I'm using DataTables to show the list of Tasks which is a Custom object, and I want to show up on the salesforce edit screen on click to edit the record.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two ways of redirecting to standard edit page of lead from your vf page onclick of your custom button if you are fetch the record id:-

```
// If you are in lightning/mobile
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {
    // Salesforce app navigation
    sforce.one.editRecord(​recordId);
}
else {
    // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
    window.location.href = 
        '{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Edit, recordId)}';
}
```

References:-

1. [Navigation and Messaging with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)
2. [Creating Visualforce Pages That Work in Mobile and Desktop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm)

Comment: Thank you Sanket it worked. also is there a way to refresh the Vf page after we Save the record?

Comment: you can use sforce.one.back(​[refresh]) to refresh. check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)

Comment: Hello Sanket, sorry for delay in my response. I'm using the sforce.one.back(true) as below but its not refreshing after save. can you please correctly what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Sanket, here is what I'm doing
if ( typeof (id) == 'string' && taskassignfieldresp.keyPrefix == id.substring(0,3)) {
         sforce.one.editRecord(id);
     } else {
         sforce.one.createRecord("dftlytime__TT_Task_Assignment__c");
     }
     sforce.one.back(true);